# Sqlite android: table not found

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I keep on getting this error saying that the table in my database doesn't exist but the table was declared.

So, I have this class to create appointments into a database, which is:

```
package com.example.calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.example.calendar.Appointment;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.KEY_DATE;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.KEY_DETAILS;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.KEY_ID;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.KEY_TIME;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.KEY_TITLE;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.TABLE_APP;


public class CreateAppointment extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText titleTextBox, timeTextBox, detailsTextBox;
    int[] dateSelected = new int[3];

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);

        titleTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.apptTitle);
        timeTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.apptTime);
        detailsTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.apptDetails);

        View createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apptSave);
        String dateToPass = null;
        Bundle getExtraFromMain = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(getExtraFromMain != null){
            dateSelected = getExtraFromMain.getIntArray(dateToPass);
        }

        createButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    private Cursor cursor(){
        DBHandler appointment = new DBHandler(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = appointment.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] getValueFrom = {KEY_DATE, KEY_TITLE, KEY_TIME, KEY_DETAILS};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_APP, getValueFrom, null, null, null, null, KEY_DATE + " ASC");
        return cursor;
    }

    private void save(){
        String getTime = timeTextBox.getText().toString();
        String getTitle = titleTextBox.getText().toString();
        String getDetails = detailsTextBox.getText().toString();
        DBHandler appointment = new DBHandler(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = appointment.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, getTitle);
        values.put(KEY_TIME, getTime);
        values.put(KEY_DETAILS, getDetails);
        values.put(KEY_DATE, dateSelected[0] + "/" + dateSelected[1] + "/" + dateSelected[2]);
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_APP, null, values);
        appointment.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.apptSave:
            save();
            finish();
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

And, of course, my handler:

```
package com.example.calendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.KEY_DATE;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.KEY_DETAILS;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.KEY_ID;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.KEY_TIME;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.KEY_TITLE;
import static com.example.calendar.Constants.TABLE_APP;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Variables needed
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "appts.db";// database name

    public DBHandler(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override//create table
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_APPOINTMENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_APP + " ("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_APPOINTMENTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override//when upgraded, trigger
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_APP);//delete table from older version
        onCreate(db);//create new table
    }


}
```

And additionally, the interface where the table name was declared:

```
package com.example.calendar;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public interface Constants extends BaseColumns{

    public static final String TABLE_APP = "appointments";// table name
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
    public static final String KEY_DETAILS = "details";

}
```

When I hit the button on the `Activity`, Logcat gives me this:

```
03-24 02:18:28.134: E/AndroidRuntime(800): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: appointments: , while compiling: INSERT INTO appointments(time,title,date,details) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
03-24 02:18:28.134: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-24 02:18:28.134: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
03-24 02:18:28.134: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
03-24 02:18:28.134: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
03-24 02:18:28.134: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1617)
03-24 02:18:28.134: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.example.calendar.CreateAppointment.save(CreateAppointment.java:69)
03-24 02:18:28.134: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.example.calendar.CreateAppointment.onClick(CreateAppointment.java:80)
```

**Note:** lines 69 and 80 are:

69:

```
db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_APP, null, values);
```

80:

```
save();//from switch statement
```

Can someone please help me??

Comment: change `DATABASE_VERSION = 1` to `DATABASE_VERSION = 2` and try again.. please give me a feedback

Comment: @Coderji works like a charm!! Thank you so much much! This also means that from now on I have to increase a number on that variable everytime i test it?

Comment: glad I could help. Ill add an answer explaining it hope you mark it as right so people can refer to it in the future

Comment: How about uninstall your app and re-install again when your table change? (instead of changing DATABASE_VERSION)..I think that may work too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code look fine, so changing the `DATABASE_VERSION = 1` to `DATABASE_VERSION = 2` may do the trick.

The reason because the `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` run only once! Therefore if you did any change within them after calling them, the change will not take affect. So changing the VERSION of the database or clearing your application data in your device/emulator could trigger to run the `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` again.

So whenever you change anything within the `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` increase the Database version.